# Problems with the memory in a booted USB

Tags: boot, usb, ram

I have got a USB bootable for Ubuntu. I installed this operating system on the USB. It actually works very well.

The problem is that when I save a file in the Home Folder, for example, when I restart the computer the file does not exist any more. It is also happening with other settings as well such as the time setting, the Keyboard format or the fact that I have to introduce the WiFi password each time.

I know that I have access to the hard drive of the computer so I can create and modify files that will always be available either from the Linux USB or from the Windows original operating system of the computer.

But I would like to have also USB memory, if you know what I mean.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must select the "persistent" option when you create the USB install media to enable you to save things.  Problems exist on UEFI machines (see bug 1159016) which require some manual fixes.

Answer (score 0):

On a live USB, things do not save - simple as that. To get stuff to save, it has to be fully installed, not 'live' (bootable on some media)

Comment: This is only true if you don't choose "persistence" when you create the USB.